Move embedded code output to <img src="'OUTPUT">
Is it possible to move output value of embedded code to a <img src''>?
The embed code example:
<!-- Paste this where you want the article to appear --> 
    <div 
    data-article="programma"
    data-param-teamcode="245124"
    data-param-gebruiklokaleteamgegevens="NEE"
    data-param-aantalregels="1"
    data-param-aantaldagen="60"
    data-param-eigenwedstrijden="JA"
    data-param-thuis="JA"
    data-param-uit="JA"
    data-format-wedstrijddatum="DD-MM-YYYY"
    data-fields="thuisteam, thuisteamlogo" 
    ></div>

has the following output:


<div data-article="programma" data-param-teamcode="245124" data-param-gebruiklokaleteamgegevens="NEE" data-param-aantalregels="1" data-param-aantaldagen="60" data-param-eigenwedstrijden="JA" data-param-thuis="JA" data-param-uit="JA" data-format-wedstrijddatum="DD-MM-YYYY"
  data-fields="thuisteam, thuisteamlogo">
  <table class="article programma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam</span></th>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam logo</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="string">De Weide 2</span></td>
        <td><span class="string">https://binaries.sportlink.com/KNVB-production-DOCUMENT/280B8A5A8EF81EC7C0CAC19267EC8683?expires=1724879248&amp;sig=a6a97cac503271e0515ce3dfd4d66b330d819e25</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



The URL in the output is a link to an image and I would like to view the image in the browser instead of just a link.
Is it possible to move this with javascript/jquery to <img src=''>??
Didn't try anything yet

It is indeed possible with jQuery to (1) query the DOM and (2) update the DOM.  When you make an attempt, where do you get stuck?  If some 3rd party tool is updating the DOM with this data then you'd certainly need to perform your logic after that takes place.  But once that has taken place, what stops you from reading the data and updating an element?

Vanilla JS - note the css to restrict the height of the logo


window.addEventListener('load',() => { // when page has loaded
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-article=programma] span.string').forEach(span => {
    const content = span.textContent.trim();
    if (content.startsWith('https')) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.classList.add('logo');
      img.src = content;
      const td = span.closest('td');
      td.textContent = ''; // empty it
      td.appendChild(img)
    }
  })
});
.logo { height: 100px; }
<div data-article="programma" data-param-teamcode="245124" data-param-gebruiklokaleteamgegevens="NEE" data-param-aantalregels="1" data-param-aantaldagen="60" data-param-eigenwedstrijden="JA" data-param-thuis="JA" data-param-uit="JA" data-format-wedstrijddatum="DD-MM-YYYY"
  data-fields="thuisteam, thuisteamlogo">
  <table class="article programma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam</span></th>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam logo</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="string">De Weide 2</span></td>
        <td><span class="string">https://binaries.sportlink.com/KNVB-production-DOCUMENT/280B8A5A8EF81EC7C0CAC19267EC8683?expires=1724879248&amp;sig=a6a97cac503271e0515ce3dfd4d66b330d819e25</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



jQuery:


$(() => { // when page has loaded
  $('[data-article=programma] span.string').each(function() {
    const $span = $(this);
    const content = $span.text().trim();
    if (content.startsWith('https')) {
      const img = $('<img>', { class:'logo', src: content });
      $span.closest('td')
      .text('') // empty it
      .append(img)
    }
  })
});
.logo { height: 100px; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-article="programma" data-param-teamcode="245124" data-param-gebruiklokaleteamgegevens="NEE" data-param-aantalregels="1" data-param-aantaldagen="60" data-param-eigenwedstrijden="JA" data-param-thuis="JA" data-param-uit="JA" data-format-wedstrijddatum="DD-MM-YYYY"
  data-fields="thuisteam, thuisteamlogo">
  <table class="article programma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam</span></th>
        <th><span class="string">Thuisteam logo</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="string">De Weide 2</span></td>
        <td><span class="string">https://binaries.sportlink.com/KNVB-production-DOCUMENT/280B8A5A8EF81EC7C0CAC19267EC8683?expires=1724879248&amp;sig=a6a97cac503271e0515ce3dfd4d66b330d819e25</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




If you're asking if you can set the SRC attribute of an IMG with JQuery, sure you can -
Say you have an image:
You can set the src attribute like this:
$("#image").attr("src","https://binaries.sportlink.com/KNVB-production-DOCUMENT/280B8A5A8EF81EC7C0CAC19267EC8683?expires=1724879248&sig=a6a97cac503271e0515ce3dfd4d66b330d819e25");
You can target images by classes or IDs and unset, swap or set almost any attribute, including src.
